# Passing a string array to system function?

Tags: c++, c

I have a string array of 3 different command line commands. Instead of writing out 3 system functions I am trying to learn how to pass a string array that holds these commands to the system function (or a similar function i.e. exec()) in a for loop. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to pass this string array into the system function one at a time. The goal is to get to exit status of each one and to break the for loop if returning an error.

```
            std::string arrString[3] = {"something","another thing","a final thing"}
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                if (system(/*Something*/))
                ;//Do something...
            }
```

**EDIT:** This outputs that an error happened, but it shouldn't.

```
                std::string arrString[4] = {"cmd","cmd","cmd"};
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                if (system(arrString[i].c_str())==0) {
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"It works!");
                }
                else
                {
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"It doesnt work :(");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) takes `char*`, so you need to call [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) on each element of your array:

```
std::string arrString[3] = {"something","another thing","a final thing"}
int i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (system(arrString[i].c_str())) {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked how I needed. Thank you. On a side note, what would be the best way to check if exit status was successful? See my edit above*

Comment: `system(...)` returns whatever the command has returned. Usually commands return zero on success, but the exact value is system-dependent. You can assign the return code to an `int` variable, and check that value to decide if the run has been successful or not.

Comment: So using something like `if (system(arrString[i].c_str())==0)` would not be the best option? I have heard that system()'s return is not always reliable. I am just trying to find the best possible solution.

Comment: `system()`'s return value is not quite that simple. The return value is in the same format as the `wait` or `waitpid` system calls. You may only care whether it's zero, though.

Comment: @mkb: So do you suggest I look into the documentation for `wait` and `waitpid`?

Comment: @arynhard: Yes, you should check the man pages for `system` and `waitpid` on your machine. The `waitpid` man page will have a bunch of macros to interpret the return code.

Answer (score 0):

```
system(arrString[i])
```

Then check exit code and break the loop if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `std:string` to a `char*` first by using the `c_str()` function:

`system(arrString[i].c_str())`